# make import of module class work globally

Tags: python, import, module

I have a python Module which holds several (inherited) classes. Lets call it foomod:

```
class Base(object):
    def interface_func(self):
        pass

class Child1(Base):
    def interface_func(self):
        #do something

class Child2(Base):
    def interface_func(self):
        #do something else
```

I used it in another script like this:

```
from foomod import Child1 as Base

def some_function(*params):
    b = Base()
    result = b.interface_func()
    #....
```

Then i choosed to make it settable via cmd arguments where the problem starts:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parse_args() #'ArgumentParser args'
    if args.child == 1:
       from foomod import Child1 as Base
    elif args.child == 2:
       from foomod import Child2 as Base
    #....
```

which gives me an error on execution:

> ... in some_function line XXX
>
> global name 'Base' is not defined

I know i could do something like this:

```
wrapper_func(child):
   if child == 1:
      from foomod import Child1 as Base
    #....
    while True:
       yield Base()

child = wrapper_func(args.child)

#usage
def some_function(*params):
    b = next(child)
```

But this just feels plain ugly...
Is there any better solution to this?

Comment: Is the `if __name__ == "__main__"` code in the same file as `some_function`?

Comment: Yes it is! I just want to make it accesible as `Base` in this file, using python 2.7 btw

Comment: What you describe should work if the imports are at the module level.  Can you provide a self-contained example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: No, I can't, because I just had played with the code and had a error in my args... and no ending else... so it was simply not defined